# Default users for MySQL 8 installation on Linux

Tags: mysql

A fresh install of MySQL 8 on Linux yields the following default users for us:

```
debian-sys-maint
mysql.infoschema
mysql.session
mysql.sys
root
```

After creating our own users, with the correct privileges, we are thinking of deleting all the users, other than root (i.e. `debian-sys-maint, mysql.infoschema, mysql.session and mysql.sys`).

---

**Q)** Is it okay to delete the default users, other than root, or will there be any unexpected surprises if we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Reserved Accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reserved-accounts.html)

You may drop `'root'@'localhost'` if you're sure that there exists at least one user with complete privileges set (compare `SHOW GRANTS` outputs !!!).

`mysql.infoschema`, `mysql.session` and `mysql.sys` are locked and cannot be used for user authentication. Do not alter them - this may cause serious problems.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/9948/what-is-the-debian-sys-maint-mysql-user-and-more), you should not remove the `debian-sys-maint` user, or your system will have problems rotating logs, and be unable to start and stop the database service.

> One major thing it is used for is telling the server to roll the logs.
> It needs at least the reload and shutdown privilege.
>
> See the file /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server
>
> It is used by the /etc/init.d/mysql script to get the status of the
> server. It is used to gracefully shutdown/reload the server.

The answer also quotes `README.debian`

```
* MYSQL WON'T START OR STOP?:
=============================
You may never ever delete the special mysql user "debian-sys-maint". This user
together with the credentials in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf are used by the init
scripts to stop the server as they would require knowledge of the mysql root
users password else.
```

---